# Load Word [MIPS] Explanation

Tags: assembly, mips

I've been searching around and haven't found a solution that makes sense to me. I am working on a project for class, and I can't seem to understand how the value is what it is based from the following correct output:

```
====================
cycle:5 120 SLL R10, R1, #2

registers:
r00:    0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0
r08:    0   0   40  0   0   0   0   0
r16:    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
r24:    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

data:
172:    -1  -2  -3  1   2   3   0   0
204:    5   -5  6   0   0   0   0   0
236:    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   10

====================
cycle:6 124 LW  R3, 172(R10)

registers:
r00:    0   10  0   6   0   0   0   0
r08:    0   0   40  0   0   0   0   0
r16:    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
r24:    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

data:
172:    -1  -2  -3  1   2   3   0   0
204:    5   -5  6   0   0   0   0   0
236:    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   10
```

What I'm getting at, why is the value in register 3 a '6' and not '39' for cycle 6.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: `39` doesn't even appear in memory anywhere; how are you expecting `lw` to load that value from memory at address = 172+R10?

Comment: @Peter Corders Every website I found says to add the offset and register together, that's at least what I took from it. I'm getting 39 from adding -1 to 40.

Comment: But R10=40 = 10 << 2, according to the table.  172+40 = 212.  A left shift can't produce a value of `-1` (all bits set), so that definitely rules out your mis-interpretation of which entries in the table are registers and which are memory.

Comment: I have little experience with assembly, but your latest comment was very informative. Adding the value of the register to data instruction outputs the correct value every time. This was the answer I was looking for so thank you.

Comment: Whatever book taught you the `lw` instruction should have explained what `172(r10)` means.